# OpenCV kmeans error: (-215) python

Tags: python, opencv, k-means

**Error:** error: (-215) (unsigned)labels[i] < (unsigned)K in function kmeans

**self.cluster[i]** represents some calculated pixel position.

```
img = numpy.asarray(img)
Z = img.reshape((-1,3))
Z = numpy.float32(Z)
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
#prepare centers
labels = numpy.zeros(k)
for i in range(k):
    labels[i] = self.cluster[i].j * img.shape[0] + self.cluster[i].i
print(Z)
ret, label, center = cv2.kmeans(Z, k, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS, labels)
```

I have read the other posts about the same error in c++, but I could not get it to work. Please help!

**EDIT1:**

```
import numpy as np
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages')
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img, (90,90))
Z = img.reshape((-1,3))

# convert to np.float32
Z = np.float32(Z)

# define criteria, number of clusters(K) and apply kmeans()
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
K = 4

labels = np.zeros(K)
labels[0] = 1
labels[1] = 100
labels[2] = 500
labels[3] = 1000
print(labels)
print(Z.shape)
ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(Z,K,None,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS, labels)

# Now convert back into uint8, and make original image
center = np.uint8(center)
res = center[label.flatten()]
res2 = res.reshape((img.shape))

cv2.imshow('res2',res2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You can run this code alone to check what's wrong. By resizing the image to less than 90x90 causes it to crash. Anything bigger than 91x91 works. Can anyone explain why and maybe how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I cannot directly copy-paste your snippet to try: it misses some definitions (meaning `k`, `self` etc). Providing an example of failing image would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem solved when using `cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS` or `cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS` instead of `cv2.KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS`.